# Tricky Riddle, Wordplay heavy, What is my name?

Tags: riddle, cipher, wordplay, lateral-thinking, knowledge

Today, I have what I consider a tricky riddle for you to answer. Please note, I have added the correct tags to this riddle.

---

I have some math problems that I need help solving. Do you think you'd be able to help me? I think I can solve the first two, but I'm struggling with the rest, especially the last question.

> Please solve the problems below. No calculators may be used when solving these problems.
> 18. log<sub>bin</sub>(1809) = 212
> 19. d/dx F(x) = 912x<sup>4</sup> - 12x<sup>3</sup> + 123x<sup>2</sup> - 255x + 18
> 20. Make the statement true: 5 (?) 12 (?) 5 (?) 16 (?) 8 (?) 1 (?) 14 (?) 20 = 1854
> 21. How is the following true? 65 - 61 = 6
>
> ---
>
> Using the above answers, please solve for the following:
> 22. A man with two friends named Parker and Ford, goes into a photo booth looking to take some pictures with his friends. Each ticket booth takes a picture once every half second, and the timer of the ticket booth is 4.15 minutes per person in the booth. If each picture taken is 5 cents, then how tall was the first man?

Bonus:
If you can actually solve the problems, that would be cool too, though that's not as important.

Hint:

> It may seem daunting at first to tackle this riddle, but just take a closer look at each line. It may not be as difficult as you think it is. No math is needed to solve this puzzle.

Comment: Joe, you come up with some crafty puzzles! +1

Comment: @PerpetualJ, thanks, I try my best :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think this part needs a spoiler tag:

**6 ft 4 in**

18.

> So I don't understand most of the clues, but I do know this is referencing Abraham Lincoln.  The first clue is about him being born in a log cabin in 1809

20.

> Elected in 1854

21.

> 1861 - Start of the Civil War, 1865, second inaugural address

22.

> Ford's Theater, bodyguard John Parker and assassin John Wilkes *Booth*

Comment: That is correct, though you are missing some stuff I threw in there. Take El-Guest for example, he solved one of the clues.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know Cool!  This is the first puzzle on SE that I've solved first :)

Answer (score 5):

@Chris Sunami has had some good suggestions which I'll try to flesh out a bit more:

Is your name

> ABRAHAM LINCOLN?

18.

> Abe Lincoln was born in a log cabin on February 12, 1809 (1809-2-12).

19.

> The A1Z26 of the numbers 9-12-12-1-23-25-5-18 read "IL LAWYER", because Abe Lincoln was a lawyer from Illinois.

20.

> The A1Z26 translation of the numbers read "ELEPHANT = 1854", because the Elephant (Republican) party was founded in 1854. (That said, Lincoln wasn't elected leader of it until 1859-1860ish.)

  21.

> Abraham Lincoln was president (the 16th president) from 1861 to 1865. 65-61 = 6, because at the end of Pres. Lincoln's term, he was 6 feet underground (credit to @Joe-You-Know for the macabre humour!)

  22.

> This contains references to Lincoln's substitute bodyguard, John Parker, and Ford's Theatre; where Lincoln was shot by John Wilkes Booth.

Comment: You're right, this is where I have a good chuckle and tell you that you're wildly, wildly off base save for problem 20. Everything before the equals sign is correct, but after that, it is just a number, which doesn't need to be deciphered.

Comment: The lateral thinking tag is heavily used in this puzzle.

Comment: But decoding 1854 as red seems to be quite fitting ...

Comment: Oh, BTW, for 19, you were really close originally. You just didn't translate the numbers correctly.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know How does this look? That was a mental mistake on the translation for 19! I'm not certain about the 65-61 = 6 part still, I just have 65-61...

Comment: You got it. Nice job.

Comment: Are there any other clues that I'm still missing?

Comment: @El-Guest, well, I was kind of making an ill-tasting joke for 65-61 = 6. 6 representing, 6 feet under.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know, quite honestly, I wish I could upvote your question twice, just for that joke. Since I can't +2, please have a complimentary 10/10.